# Angular2 get content from txt file via http

Tags: angular, http

I want to get a simple text from a file on my webserver ( [Text File](http://test.torbengabriel.de/data/articles/article.txt) )

This is my http call:

```
getArticle() {
    this.http.get('http://test.torbengabriel.de/data/articles/article.txt').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data.text());
  });
  }
```

I got an error (but with a status code 200):

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token K in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "Kommen wir nun einmal zu einigen Hilfsmitteln, mit… das
```

So he gets the file. The Text ("Kommen wir nun einmal...") is correct. But the console.log will never be called and i cannot work with the data. What is my mistake? 
I hope someone could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the new `HttpClient`, the default response type is JSON, so it will try to parse it as such. Instead of calling `.text()`, you now need to specify the return type of `text` like so:

```
this.http.get('http://test.torbengabriel.de/data/articles/article.txt', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('data', data);
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works, i love you :) i am very happy. really, big big thanks

Comment: @TorbenG Haha, glad I could help